# PCSX not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: emulation, pcsx

I have downloaded PCSX from The Ubuntu Software Center and the BIOS file from http://www.emuparadise.me/biosfiles/bios.html (PSX BIOS Pack (15 Images)). When I try to run an .iso file or from the CD-drive (yes, the games are original), the screen turns black and then it crashes after 5 seconds or so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Please edit '~/.pcsx/pcsx.cfg' like this.

  ==> change 'Cpu = 0' to 'Cpu = 1'

(*) I refer to this HP.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcsxr/+bug/1504834

Comment: it still doesn't run for me after following this

Comment: I'm using pcsxr, but I had the same problem and this fixed it. Why would somebody ship software in a broken state like this? It's such a small fix.

Comment: try getting ePSXe with the bios file SCPH1001.BIN it will work on ubuntu 18.04