# PCSX Not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: emulation, pcsx

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit on a HP Notebook with a quad-core AMD processor and four gigs of RAM

I'm still relatively new to all of this but I can usually figure out how to get most emulators running.

However, PCSX-Reloaded 1.9.92 is not one of those emulators, and I've been trying to get it working for days.

The details:

I have the graphics set to Open GL.

I edited the pcsx.cfg file to Cpu = 1.

I have a SCPH7001 bios file but in the PCSX configuration/plugins&bios tab I can't change the bios file--as in there is no option in the graphic interface that will actually let me change the bios--or is there something I'm missing?

I'd be happy to try the drag and drop method but to where and how?

I also have a game rom, a bin file, and when I open it from the PCSX interface a black screen pops up for a moment like it's going to work and then the app just crashes and disappears.

What am I missing? Emulating shouldn't be rocket science--if I cannot get help here then where can I find a user-friendly comprehensive guide to the PCSX?

Update: I've successfully placed the BIOS file in the PCSX BIOS directory. Now I cannot even attempt to open a game rom as clicking the folder icon only opens up what you see in the screen shot, where configuration buttons appear to be disabled. Why is this?
[PCSX Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvrzg.png)

Comment: You can check this question for additional information http://askubuntu.com/questions/787370/pcsx-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: I already did that--this didn't help.

Comment: The point was getting a link for the BIOS which needs to be saved in a certain folder.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2314767

Comment: Apparently BIOS SCPH7502 is the preferred one according to this (in Spanish): http://www.misjuegosenlinux.com/2013/09/pcsx-reloaded-emulando-tu.html

Comment: Update: I just successfully moved the SPCH7001 BIOS file to the correct directory.

Comment: However, now when I click on the folder icon from within the PCSX app, I no longer have the option of selecting a rom. Also, other configuration buttons are not there: see screen shot please:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52089/discussion-between-sean-valdivia-and-celticwarrior).