# PCSXR get to work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: pcsx

I'm trying PCSXR emulator for PSX, but it get closed and never loads a game...

I have to say... I got the needed BIOS files, controllers, graphix, ISO's etc... but still don't run neither the bios... 
I've already tried to run another game, change the BIOS, the memcards, I changed the "CPU" from "0" to "1" in the "pcsxr.cfg" file as it says here [PCSX not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787370/pcsx-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) and here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcsxr/+bug/1504834 but nothing...

What can I do?

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: I am also in the same situation. I find Ubuntu 18 is incompatible with a lot of old software, IMHO the best thing to do is to stay away from Ubuntu 18.